# How is CY or CURRENCY union used in VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, com, variant

I have to handle Variant type VT_CY in the server I am working on. This is link to the data type.

[CURRENCY union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221223(v=vs.85).aspx)

Although it describes the type, I could not find any example of its usage. Please provide the example for the same.

Comment: Divide the `int64` member with `10000.0` and you'll have a floating point value.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What about Hi and Lo? If I want to convert a double value say 4655757.1234, how will it convert to CY?

Comment: If you can use native 64-bit math then why bother with those members? And to convert the opposite way, think about what the opposite of division is.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh, I thought all fields were required. You mean to say int64 holds the entire value? 4655757.1234 should be stored as 46557571234 in int64 ? I didn't notice it was a union.

Comment: As an aside, the value `4655757.1234` cannot accurately be represented as a finite double-precision floating point value. This may or may not be important to your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other commenters have noted, the structure of a `CY` is well-known, and you can therefore program your own conversions and manipulations. However, I usually prefer to rely on the API that Microsoft has provided for `CY` instances. Take a look at the following links.

- [Currency Arithmetic Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221515(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Data Type Conversion Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221508(v=vs.85).aspx)

You should try to limit conversion as much as possible. If you have two `CY` structs, use arithmetic functions like [`VarCyAdd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221636(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of converting the `CY` structs to floating-point types. This will reduce floating point errors. When you have manipulated the `CY` structs as appropriate, you can use [`VarBstrFromCy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221218(v=vs.85).aspx) to generate a string representation of the value. Again, this is better than converting the final result to a floating-point value before formatting the floating-point value to a string.

All of the previous holds true for `DECIMAL` types as well.

- [Decimal Arithmetic Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221612(v=vs.85).aspx)

There are similar functions for `VARIANT` structs. If you have two `VARIANT` structs that contain numeric values (anything from an `INT` to a `DECIMAL` to a `CY`), you can use functions like [`VarAdd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221574(v=vs.85).aspx) to add the two `VARIANT` structs in a well-defined manner. For example, if you call that function on two `VARIANT` structs that each contain a `CY` value, the result will be a `VARIANT` containing a new `CY` value. If you add a `VARIANT` containing a `CY` to a `VARIANT` containing a `DECIMAL`, you end up with a `VARIANT` containing a `DECIMAL`.

- [Variant Arithmetic Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221430(v=vs.85).aspx)